# C++ syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++-cli

Ehh, I'm having an issue which i don't understand...

```
class ManagedGlobals
{
public: gcroot<Editor^> MainEditor;
};
```

Why does my compiler give me:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Why?

Comment: Your error probably comes from `gcroot` not being declared yet, but `^` as a pointer is not C++.

Comment: @chris No, it's not valid C++.  This looks to be Managed C++ (aka C++/CLI).  I've retagged the question.

Comment: @cdhowie, Oh, I was going off the tag.

Comment: Did you specify the compilation flag to tell the compiler it is C++/CLI? Did you include <vcclr.h>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this?

```
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace System;
```

[Here's a full example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of using gcroot.