# C++ & C++ Cli Wont accept .net form

Tags: .net, c++-cli, native, managed

First of all, i have two codes:

ManagedGlobalsDeclaration.h

```
#ifndef MGD_H
#define MGD_H

#include "Editor.h"
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace Cube3D;

namespace Cube3D {
    class ManagedGlobals
    {
        public: 
            gcroot<Editor ^> MainEditor;
    };
}

#endif
```

Editor.h

```
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H

#include "System.h"                     
#include "AddRenderingPipelineCommand.h"
#include "AddMaterial.h"                
#include "P_Material.h"             
#include "P_UMesh.h"                    
#include "Log.h"
#include "ManagedGlobals.h"             //     <------ Error!

#include <vcclr.h>

namespace Cube3D {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    void LoopRender(void);
    void GetRenderingOrder(void);
    String^ GetListbox2Item();

    TextureObject InstancedTexturing[10];
    UMesh InstancedMesh[10];

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Editor
    /// </summary>
    ref class Editor : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        // Bla bla bla....
```

ManagedGlobals.h

```
#ifndef MG_H
#define MG_H

#include "ManagedGlobals_Declaration.h"

extern ManagedGlobals MG;

#endif
```

But my compiler tells me that it doesn't know Editor, in ManagedGlobalsDeclaration. The class ManagedGlobals is declared in ManagedGLobalsDeclaration.h, and is then(somewhere else) actually defined, so thats why i make a header just to use the extern. But why doesn't it recognize Editor?

```
Error 29 error C2065: 'Editor' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this question in different ways?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548947/c-using-gcroot-in-header-file-for-managed-class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419459/c-declaring-a-managed-variable-in-a-native-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567792/c-syntax-error-missing-before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular include. Try using a forward declaration instead:

```
#ifndef MGD_H
#define MGD_H

#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace Cube3D;

namespace Cube3D {
    ref class Editor;

    class ManagedGlobals
    {
        public: 
            gcroot<Editor ^> MainEditor;
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: Worked great, but then in another header file, where it included ManagedGlobals, it says alot of stuff isn't a part of the MG.MainEditor, which is completely false, maybe its the forward declaration's fault?

Comment: You should move the implementations to .cpp files so for you can use forward declarations in your class declarations and include the headers in the .cpp files.

Comment: @user1492812, I agree that you should move your implementation to .cpp files. Even if you don't, then wherever you try to call anything on `MainEditor`, you need to include both these headers, not just `ManagedGlobalsDeclaration.h`